# Append to meeting invite body with or without Redemption

Tags: vsto, outlook-addin, outlook-redemption

We are developing an Outlook VSTO add-in.

Right now I am trying to append some information to a meeting invite the user is in the process of composing. I want the content to appear in the body like what clicking the Teams-meeting button would do, where formatted text and links are appended to the end of the body.

Since the content is HTML and the Outlook Object Model does not expose an HTMLBody property for AppointmentItems, I try to set it via Redemption:

```cs
// Dispose logic left out for clarity but everything except outlookApplication and outlookAppointment is disposed after use
Application outlookApplication = ...;
AppointmentItem outlookAppointment = ...;  // taken from the open inspector
NameSpace outlookSession = outlookApplication.Session;

RDOSession redemptionSession = RedemptionLoader.new_RDOSession();
redemptionSession.MAPIOBJECT = outlookSession.MAPIOBJECT;
var rdoAppointment = (RDOAppointmentItem)redemptionSession.GetRDOObjectFromOutlookObject(outlookAppointment);

string newBody = transform(rdoAppointment.HTMLBody);  // appends content right before HTML </body> tag
rdoAppointment.BodyFormat = (int)OlBodyFormat.olFormatHTML;
rdoAppointment.HTMLBody = newBody;
```

### Problem

The Outlook inspector window is not updating with the appended content. If I try to run the code again, I can see the appended content in the debugger, but not in Outlook.

Things I have tried:

1. Saving the RDOAppointmentItem
2. Also adding the content to Body property
3. Using SafeAppointmentItem instead of RDOAppointmentItem; didn't work because HTMLBody is a read-only property there
4. Setting PR_HTML via RDOAppointment.Fields
5. Paste the HTML via WordEditor (see below)

### Attempt to use WordEditor

Per suggestion I also attempted to insert the HTML via WordEditor:

```cs
// Dispose logic left out for clarity but everything except inspector is disposed after use
string htmlSnippet = ...;
Clipboard.SetText(htmlSnippet, TextDataFormat.Html);
Inspector inspector = ...;
Document wordDoc = inspector.WordEditor;
Range range = wordDoc.Content;
range.Collapse(WdCollapseDirection.wdCollapseEnd);
object placement = WdOLEPlacement.wdInLine;
object dataType = WdPasteDataType.wdPasteHTML;
range.PasteSpecial(Placement: ref placement, DataType: ref dataType);
```

... but I simply receive the error `System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x800A1066): Kommandoen lykkedes ikke.` (= "Command failed").

Instead of PasteSpecial I also tried using PasteAndFormat:

```cs
range.PasteAndFormat(WdRecoveryType.wdFormatOriginalFormatting);
```

... but that also gave `System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x800A1066): Kommandoen lykkedes ikke.`.

What am I doing wrong here?

EDIT: If I use `Clipboard.SetText(htmlSnippet, TextDataFormat.Text);` and then use plain `range.Paste();`, the HTML is inserted at the end of the document as intended (but with the HTML elements inserted literally, so not useful). So the general approach seems to be okay, I just can't seem to get Outlook / Word to translate the HTML.

### Version info

Outlook 365 MSO 32-bit
Redemption 5.26

Answer (score 2):

Per Dmitrys suggestion, here is a working solution that:

1. Shows the inserted content in the inspector window.
2. Handles HTML content correctly with regards to both links and formatting (as long as you stay within the limited capabilities of Words HTML engine).

```cs
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using Outlook = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook;
using Word = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;

namespace VSTO.AppendHtmlExample
{
    public class MyExample
    {
        public void AppendAsHTMLViaFile(string content)
        {
            // TODO: Remember to release COM objects range and wordDoc and delete output file in a finally clause
            Outlook.Inspector inspector = ...;
            string outputFolderPath = ...;
            string outputFilePath = Path.Combine(outputFolderPath, "append.html");

            Word.Document wordDoc = inspector.WordEditor;
            File.WriteAllText(outputFilePath, $"<html><head><meta charset='utf-8'/></head><body>{content}</body></html>", Encoding.UTF8);

            Word.Range range = wordDoc.Content;
            range.Collapse(Word.WdCollapseDirection.wdCollapseEnd);

            object confirmConversions = false;
            object link = false;
            object attachment = false;

            range.InsertFile(fileName,
                ConfirmConversions: ref confirmConversions,
                Link: ref link,
                Attachment: ref attachment);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the appointment is being displayed, work with the Word Object Model - `Inspector.WordEditor` returns the `Document` Word object.

Comment: Hi Dmitry, I tried to use WordEditor but always get "command failed" COM exception. How would I use WordEditor to insert HTML into the document, given that I have the HTML snippet in a String?

Comment: Please show your code.You can use Region.InsertFile to insert HTML content.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to write that I edited my question to show the code. It's in the "Attempt to use WordEditor" section. I was trying to use PasteSpecial or PasteAndFormat, but they both failed for HTML content. Does that mean that only InsertFile will work?

Comment: I have not used PasteSpecial (it is a bad practice to overwrite the keyboard contents), but InsertFile definitely works - I have used it multiple times.

Comment: I got it working using InsertFile, thank you! It is not a pretty solution, writing the HTML snippet out to a temporary file and then inserting. But as you said, neither is using the system clipboard.